# Eliminating "phantom" or "ghost" clicks on my Mac Pro

Tags: macos, mouse

Recently on my Mac Pro I have been experiencing phantom clicks and other strange behaviors. I have been rummaging through my system preferences to try and root out possible causes, and recently came across a strange finding in the Exposé panel (the keyboard modifiers are there from my taking the screenshot):

[image: 9 mouse buttons?]

I have had a Logitech 2-button mouse with a mouse wheel for years, and have never had a problem with it in the past. In addition I am running OS X 10.6.8 and have not had any issues like this up to this point.

Is this a known issue? Is the extensive mouse listing a red herring? Are there any fixes for either issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2321023?start=15&tstart=0) on the Apple discussions forum.

The problem seems to stem from the "Enable access for assistive device" in the Universal Access preference panel, which needed to be *disabled*. There are mixed reports as to whether or not the issue has been fixed in Lion.

It would appear the long list of mouse buttons (as in my screenshot) is a red herring.